# How to extract all type of date formats from text

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

```
str= '01-01-2020 01/01/2020 01 Oct 2020 01 October 2020'
all = re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{2,4}", str)
for s in all:
    print(s)
```

So far I have tried this one I'm getting only one format 01-01-2020 but I want extract all type of date format any help would highly appreciate

Comment: Regex is a fairly poor choice for this IMHO.  Instead, look into using Python's `datetime` library.  Maintain a set of all possible date masks, and then iterate through that set, trying each one, against each input.

Comment: If you would like to use Regex, check out this: `(?<dates>\d{2}[-\/]\d{2}[-\/]\d{4}|\d{2}.\w{3,}.\d{4})` - [online tester](https://regex101.com/r/zR2Ixn/1). For python, remove the name of group ;)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen do you have any example on this plz share it would help me more thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Initial note:** i'm not an expert of python. As @TimBiegeleisen stated in the comment to the question, using python's libraries is probably better way to achieve that.

So, i can only help you to write proper regex pattern, which is:

`(\d{2}[-\/]\d{2}[-\/]\d{4}|\d{2}.\w{3,}.\d{4})`

For further details, please see [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/zR2Ixn/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another regex, that tries to match month names as well ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eqlE05/1)):

```
import re

txt = '''
01-01-2020
01/01/2020
01 Oct 2020
01 October 2020
01 Jan 2020
01 Feb 2020
01 Mar 2020
01 May 2020
01 Jun 2020
01 Jul 2020
01 Aug 2020
01 Sep 2020
01 Oct 2020
01 Nov 2020
01 Dec 2020
12 December 1991'''

r = re.compile(r'\d{2}[ /-](?:\d{2}|Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)[ /-]\d{4}')

for d in r.findall(txt):
    print(d)
```

Prints:

```
01-01-2020
01/01/2020
01 Oct 2020
01 October 2020
01 Jan 2020
01 Feb 2020
01 Mar 2020
01 May 2020
01 Jun 2020
01 Jul 2020
01 Aug 2020
01 Sep 2020
01 Oct 2020
01 Nov 2020
01 Dec 2020
12 December 1991
```

Comment: But 01/08/12 in this format it's fail to extract format

Comment: thanks so much , if I want to extract Any one of the date when I had multiple dates in text what changes required I have tried but failed and thanks in advance ur solution was really helped

Comment: @ Andrek Kesely one more suggestion please 9/13/2018 this format not extracting can you plz help what changes required . I'm beginner here and trying if you suggest this one I really thankfull to you

Comment: @manjubadiger Change the first `\d{2}` to `\d{1,2}`

Comment: Thanks so much and one more last 2018/08/16 I have changes code but not working when year comes plz any help

Comment: @manjubadiger You can try change first `\d{1,2}` to `\d{1,4}`

Comment: Ya I have changed for 10/9/2018 for second one 1,2 so it's working but it's not working for 9/13/2018 so again I changed to second one {2} in this case only one case working  both are not working  so 10/9/2018 and 9/13/208 both should work thanks in advance

Comment: @ Andrej Kesely Hope your help me out

Comment: 7/5/2019  10/9/2018  9/10/2018 please help me for this